# variable inside variable in case of bash

Tags: bash

I have a following script where variables(`$1`) inside variable(`$ARG`) needs to be substituted:

```
#! /bin/bash

ARGS="-enable-kvm -hda /root/"$1".raw -display vnc=:"$1""

do_start()
{
          echo $ARGS
}

case "$1" in
  start)
        for i in {1..5}; do
          do_start $i
        done
        ;;
esac
```

However, if I execute the script with `./scriptname start` then output is following:

```
-enable-kvm -hda /root/start.raw -display vnc=:start
-enable-kvm -hda /root/start.raw -display vnc=:start
-enable-kvm -hda /root/start.raw -display vnc=:start
-enable-kvm -hda /root/start.raw -display vnc=:start
-enable-kvm -hda /root/start.raw -display vnc=:start
```

How to substitute variable inside variable in case of bash?

Comment: place double quotes around `$ARGS` in definition of `do_start()`

Comment: Or, rather, don't. See BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 4):

Use an array variable, per [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), defined *inside* the context where you know the value for `$i`:

```
#!/bin/bash

do_start() {
  local -a args=( -enable-kvm -hda "/root/$1.raw" -display vnc=:"$1" )
  printf '%q ' "${args[@]}"; echo # print args for the VM in shell-quoted form
  qemu "${args[@]}"               # actually start the VM
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    for ((i=1; i<=5; i++)); do
      do_start "$i"
    done
    ;;
esac
```

Note that this won't print literal quotes, but it **doesn't need to** (and, in fact, shouldn't: Content printed by `echo` is data; the quotes you care about are **syntactical**, and not data; so if `echo $args` printed quotes, this would mean that `qemu $args` wouldn't work correctly for reasons given in BashFAQ 50 -- as linked above -- which I strongly recommend reading).

Quoting will still be correct for content that needs quoting, though for integer values this will never be the case.

```
$ ./run-script start
-enable-kvm -hda /root/1.raw -display vnc=:1
-enable-kvm -hda /root/2.raw -display vnc=:2
-enable-kvm -hda /root/3.raw -display vnc=:3
-enable-kvm -hda /root/4.raw -display vnc=:4
-enable-kvm -hda /root/4.raw -display vnc=:5
```

Escaping the backslash before the space has the same effect as putting literal quotes around content: It still ensures that the filename is viewed as a single string.

---

If you then want to run qemu with your arguments:

```
qemu "${args[@]}"
```

...will do the trick correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by declaring `ARGS` locally and fixing your quotes

```
do_start()
{
    ARGS="-enable-kvm -hda /root/$1.raw -display vnc=:"$1"
    echo "$ARGS"
}
```

Note that depending on the form your arguments are expected to take, this approach is prone to errors and a more robust way is shown by @Charles Duffy

Comment: This doesn't make the command actually _work_ when `$1` contains spaces, glob characters, etc. (And what was the point of quoting the `$1` expansion in the first place if it couldn't?)

Comment: agreed and a different solution completely is probably the way to go. I was just showing how to fix it in the current scope and definition

Comment: One additional minor note, by the way -- `ARGS` is actually being declared as a global here, even though that declaration is inside a function. Using `local` or `declare` (inside a function) will make it _actually_ a local.

Comment: I meant locally as where to define it, I was not referring to the scope. Unfortunate choice of words on my part :)

Answer (score -1):

First you have to change you double-quotes to single-quotes so that the `$1` won't disappear on initial assignment. Then to get it evaluated at the time you want it to happen you can use the `eval` command.

```
#! /bin/bash

args=' -enable-kvm -hda "/root/$1.raw" -display vnc=:"$1" '

do_start()
{
    #echo "1=$1"
    eval "echo $args"
}

case "$1" in
  start)
        for i in {1..5}; do
          do_start $i
        done
        ;;
esac
```

Results:

```
$ ./foo.sh start
-enable-kvm -hda /root/1.raw -display vnc=:1
-enable-kvm -hda /root/2.raw -display vnc=:2
-enable-kvm -hda /root/3.raw -display vnc=:3
-enable-kvm -hda /root/4.raw -display vnc=:4
-enable-kvm -hda /root/5.raw -display vnc=:5
```

Comment: ...if you let untrusted users set port numbers, for instance, consider the course of events if a port number were given containing `123$(rm -rf .)`

Comment: It's not a security risk if your program is completely defining the value of the variable - it's not like you're getting it from the user or something.

Comment: It's bad practice/habit though. And as pointed out, it's unnecessary. Why use it if there are better alternatives?

Comment: Argh. I misread what the OP was doing here, and my above objection was based on same. This isn't as dangerous as I took it for -- though using `eval` unnecessarily is still something I object to on principal (as even when something is safe as originally written, code gets repurposed and used in new ways and scenarios, and not always with a new security evaluation).

Comment: If this is a script for the front-line defense of the DoD (yes, that's an exaggeration) then I'm 100% agreed. But if this is a program I'm running on my local system to make my life easy (about 99% of my use of bash scripts) then I would argue that (1) the ease/simplicity and (2) the fact that the input is absolutely checked before used make it that this is an acceptable use of bash. You're all right to caution the indiscriminate or habitual use, but I there are times when it is entirely acceptable and, depending on how the OP is going to use this, this seems to me to be a likely candidate.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from -- but at the same time, what is habit but the result of repeated action? The places where correctness failures are most dangerous are those where one may not necessarily realize that correctness is essential; one of my favorite stories to tell is at a former shop where an unquoted expansion in a shell script deleted TB of backups after a buffer overflow put garbage into a filename (in a directory where, at the time when the faulty script was written, names could _"never possibly"_ fail to match `[0-9a-f]{32}`... until, of course, they did).